# Oracle concat a dynamic value

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update a table column with values that are derieved. To add little more complexity, I need to concat a value based on the derivate and hence the value to append for concat is not always the same. I came up with this query, but it apparently has a problem executing.

```
    update TRANSFER set PROCESS_STATUS = concat ( PREDICATE , 
                (select dom_value from DOMAIN_VALUES dv where dv.val_id = st.sr_cashflow_status
CASE PREDICATE WHEN dv.dom_value = 'ZZZZ' THEN 'SPB'
                         WHEN dv.dom_value = 'XXXX' THEN 'SPB'
                         WHEN dv.dom_value = 'YYYY' THEN 'SPB'
              ELSE 'DPS'
                         END ))         from TRANSFER st
    where PROCESS_STATUS is null;
```

My main problem is that how do I maintain the appender (here, predicate) as dynamic value that can be checked on the value obtained by join?

Any answers/directions much appreciated.

Comment: First of all, It should be **st* instead of **ts**.
You could use Subquery and then Concat it.
IF you still face the problem Please Post the SCHEMA And the proper Problem Statement.

Comment: Yes, please post the schema. I assume PREDICATE belongs to the TRANSFER table? I'm also not certain that your CASE statement makes sense -- could you indicate exactly what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear with my question. Schema looks like this - TRANSFER(ID, CASHFLOW, .... , CASHFLOW_STATUS, PROCESS_STATUS...), DOMAIN_VALUES(ID, TYPE, VALUE). I need to update values of PROCESS_STATUS by taking CASHFLOW_STATUS which is a fk on DOMAIN_VALUES(hence I need to join with DOMAIN_VALUES to get the value of "VALUE") and then concat this with a string. This string to concat inturn depends on the value of VALUE from DOMAIN_VALUES and hence I used the case.

Comment: @DheerajJoshi Thanks for noticing, although it was just a typo. In my original query I had st and not ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to achieve something like below (considering `PREDICATE` is a column in `TRANSFER` table)-

```
MERGE INTO TRANSFER st 
   using (select CASE 
            WHEN dv.dom_value = 'ZZZZ' THEN 'SPB'
            WHEN dv.dom_value = 'XXXX' THEN 'SPB'
            WHEN dv.dom_value = 'YYYY' THEN 'SPB'
            ELSE 'DPS'
            END as key,
            val_id
           from DOMAIN_VALUES) dv
      on (dv.val_id = st.sr_cashflow_status and st.PROCESS_STATUS is NULL)         
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
         UPDATE SET PROCESS_STATUS = concat(PREDICATE,dv.key);
```

OR

```
MERGE INTO TRANSFER st 
       using (select CASE 
                WHEN dv.dom_value = 'ZZZZ' THEN 'SPB'
                WHEN dv.dom_value = 'XXXX' THEN 'SPB'
                WHEN dv.dom_value = 'YYYY' THEN 'SPB'
                ELSE 'DPS'
                END as key,
                val_id
               from DOMAIN_VALUES) dv
          on (dv.val_id = st.sr_cashflow_status and st.PROCESS_STATUS is NULL)         
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
             UPDATE SET PROCESS_STATUS = PREDICATE||dv.key;
```

A quick note on your `CASE` statement syntax. The syntax looks incorrect since you do not compare the outcome of the `CASE` with anything since you are using this in a `WHERE` clause, also you are missing `AND` clause too.

```
update TRANSFER set PROCESS_STATUS = concat ( PREDICATE , 
                (select dom_value from DOMAIN_VALUES dv where dv.val_id =            st.sr_cashflow_status
                   CASE PREDICATE WHEN dv.dom_value = 'ZZZZ' THEN 'SPB' -- and clause missing
                         WHEN dv.dom_value = 'XXXX' THEN 'SPB'
                         WHEN dv.dom_value = 'YYYY' THEN 'SPB'
                   ELSE 'DPS'
                         END ))         --comparison missing like CASE ... END = 'SPB' since the case is inside WHERE
       from TRANSFER st                 -- you cannot have a FROM clause in UPDATE
    where PROCESS_STATUS is null;
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I don't have much experience with MERGE but USING clause should contain source data to be updated, right? Here putting CASE in select doesn't somehow seem right to me. I put some more explanation of my problem.

Comment: USING should have the datasource or table with which you want to join the actual table which you want to update. `USING` can have a select query or an inline view instead of a table, the `CASE` statement is correct. I have no idea what you columns mean, but this is the closest to what I can assume your end result should look like. FYI- the way you used the case statement is incorrect since you are not comparing the out put of the `case` to anything and you are using it in a `where` clause. See [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:237794600346808562).

Comment: Well, it wasn't exactly the answer I was looking for, but your answer inspired me to consider merge and finally I got my work done. Thanks.